# pandas - create customer movement matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
customer_id,month,Group,category,days_ago
A1,Jan,Premium,saf,13
A1,Jan,Premium,ewf,54
A2,Jan,Lost,ds,32
A3,Jan,Lost,dfs,78
A4,Jan,Lost,sdfg,94
A5,Jan,Loyal,sa,14
A6,Jan,Need Attention,ewf,13

A1,Mar,Premium,efWCC,78
A2,Mar,Need Attention,POI
A3,Mar,Lost,QWE
A4,Mar,Need Attention,QOEP
A4,Mar,Need Attention,POTU
A5,Mar,Loyal,FANC
A6,Mar,Lost,FAS
A7,Mar,New,qewr
A8,Mar,New,wqer

t1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Create a matrix against Jan and Mar month

b) Fill the matrix with customer count under each group

I expect my output to be in a table like as below

[image]

I tried the below but not sure how to get everything in a neat table

```
cust_info = t1.groupby(['customer_id','month','Group']).size().reset_index()
group_info = t1.groupby(['customer_id','Group']).size().reset_index()
group_info.merge(cust_info,on='customer_id',how='left')
```

Is there anyway to capture their movement from one group another between the months `Jan` and `Mar`? I have a big data of 20K customers. Is there any elegant way to produce the below output?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge` of filtered DataFrames with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = df[df['month'].eq('Jan')].merge(df[df['month'].eq('Mar')], on='customer_id')

df = pd.crosstab([df['month_x'], df['Group_x']], [df['month_y'], df['Group_y']])
print (df)
month_y                 Mar                             
Group_y                Lost Loyal Need Attention Premium
month_x Group_x                                         
Jan     Lost              1     0              2       0
        Loyal             0     1              0       0
        Need Attention    1     0              0       0
        Premium           0     0              0       1
```

IIUC use:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['month','customer_id','customer_id', 'Group'])

df = df[df['month'].eq('Jan')].merge(df[df['month'].eq('Mar')], 
                                     on='customer_id', 
                                     how='outer').fillna('no match')

df = pd.crosstab([df['month_x'], df['Group_x']], [df['month_y'], df['Group_y']])
print (df)
month_y                  Mar                                 
Group_y                 Lost Loyal Need Attention New Premium
month_x  Group_x                                             
Jan      Lost              1     0              2   0       0
         Loyal             0     1              0   0       0
         Need Attention    1     0              0   0       0
         Premium           0     0              0   0       1
no match no match          0     0              0   2       0
```

Comment: I tried this and get the same error message as below - `ValueError: aggfunc cannot be used without values.`. I wish to count only unique customer ids. In my real data, for each month there could be multiple rows for each customer. So, we have to get unique count. When I used `aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique`, I get the error mentioned

Comment: @TheGreat - If change `df = df[df['month'].eq('Jan')].merge(df[df['month'].eq('Mar')], on='customer_id')` to `df = df.drop_duplicates(['month','customer_id','customer_id'])` `df = df[df['month'].eq('Jan')].merge(df[df['month'].eq('Mar')], on='customer_id')` it working?

Comment: yes, works but one new issue. We cannot do inner join. Because new customers may be added in Mar (who were not in Jan). So, if we do inner join, it will only count common customers. Right? So, should we do outer join?

Comment: @TheGreat - yop, use outer join.

Comment: some discrepancy with the count obtained.

Comment: @TheGreat - Is possible change data for test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252247/discussion-between-the-great-and-jezrael).

Comment: @TheGreat - Tested and for me workng well from sample data

Comment: uploaded sample screenshot in chat window. have a look. I show the issue in outut

Comment: It has missed the `New` value for group. It is only picking common group values. In Mar we have a new value called `New` under group column for two new customers (which is not there in Jan). So, it is missing that

Comment: @TheGreat - what is expected ouput? Added solution to answer, but not sure it need it.

Answer (score 2):

Lets do dot product for efficient calculation

```
s = pd.crosstab([t1['month'], t1['Group']], t1['customer_id'])
s.loc['Jan'] @ s.loc['Mar'].T
```

Result

```
Group           Lost  Loyal  Need Attention  Premium
Group                                               
Lost               1      0               2        0
Loyal              0      1               0        0
Need Attention     1      0               0        0
Premium            0      0               0        1
```

Comment: Nice. what does `@` symbol indicate in 2nd line of code?

Comment: Its the syntactical sugar for dot product basically `@` is for calculating dot product

Comment: I tried this in real data. Is there anyway to make sure that customer ids are not counted twice? Because in my real data, the same customer may appear multiple times for each month (unlike sample data where each customer has only one row). but in real data, each customer may have multiple rows (but his group assignment for that month will be constant). So, now instead of just count, we need to distinct count (nunique). Is there a way to dthis? since it's big data, my numbers are inflated and am sure it is because of counting each row as a customer. But it should not

Comment: I already tried `aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique` but it threw a message that `ValueError: aggfunc cannot be used without values.`

Comment: also note, my real data has multiple columns (ex: 64 columns). While customer id and group value remains same in a month, other column values change for each customer (ex: product purchased, date of purchase etc)

Comment: I tried something like this - `s = pd.crosstab([result['month'], result['group']],result['customer_id'],aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)` but got an error message

Comment: I updated your code by adding keywords but still dot product gives all `NA`. Full table is `NA`. Code looks like below -  `s = pd.crosstab(index=[result['month'], result['group']],columns=result['group'],values=result['customer_id'],aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)`. This gives the count for each group (and each month correctly). When I do dot product, it gives all `NA`

Comment: SImple.. Just clip the values `s.loc['Jan'].ne(0) @ s.loc['Mar'].T.ne(0)`

Comment: It gives `True` for everything

Comment: I meant `(s.loc['Jan'].clip(upper=1) @ s.loc['Mar'].T.clip(upper=1))` :-)

Comment: or just modify `crosstab`: `pd.crosstab([t1['month'], t1['Group']], t1['customer_id']).clip(upper=1)`

Comment: No, if I use `clip` in cross tab, it just gives `1` for the groups (and does not show the original count of customers under each group for each month). Later, when I apply dot product, it still gives True for everything. I updated the sample data

Comment: Its working for me. please check again. https://imgur.com/a/YhMsPpN

Comment: your image doesn't open. I have pasted the output image above in my post (for new sample data with multiple rows for a customer). can have a look and let me know where am i making mistake?

Comment: Also note that we have new value called `New` for group column in Mar for 2 new customers. It is only picking common group values. In Mar we have a new value called New under group column for two new customers (which is not there in Jan). So, it is missing that